# closest() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, width

```
$("#main .primary")
        .width($(this).closest("#main .row")
        .outerWidth(true) - $(this).closest("#main .secondary")
        .outerWidth(true));
```

..doesn't work at all.

What I'm doing is applying the width to the `primary` div by subtracting the width of `secondary` from `main` (parent).

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="primary"></div>
        <div class="secondary"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: show your html code may be you repeated yourself with same dom ID.

Comment: some html will help to get an answer

Comment: @Ahmad updated with html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the selector `#main .row` will return an empty jQuery Object,
if you want to match the element having an id and a class together you can use it like this :

```
#myId.my-class // Select by id and class
div#myId.my-class // Select by element and the id and the class
```

I suggest for you to use the siblings() method in your case

```
$('#main .primary')
  .width( function(){ 
   return $(this).closest('.row').width() - // or you can use .parent() instead
          $(this).siblings('.secondary').outerWidth(true); 
})
```

Comment: the first part is not related. I dont see in his question where he thought he needed both id and class on the same element.

Comment: @RoyiNamir he is using it in `.closest("#main .row")` which is invalid in this case because `#main` and `.row` are the same element

Comment: where do you see at its html that they are the same ?>

Comment: @RoyiNamir , OK you are right the question was edit after I answered, they was the same element, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Hope below solution will help you.

Didn't tested because having no time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

    var main      = $("#main");
    var primary   = main.find('.row > .primary');
    var secondary = main.find('.row > .secondary');
    var newWidth  = main.width() - secondary.width() ;

    console.log(newWidth);
    primary.css('width',newWidth);
});

</script>

<div id="main" style="border:5px solid red;padding:10px;width:600px;">
    <div class="row" style="border:5px solid red;padding:10px;width:500px;">
        <div class="primary" style="border:2px solid #CCC;width:200px;padding:10px;"></div>
        <div class="secondary" style="border:5px solid #669900;width:200px;padding:10px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its recommended to use `outerWidth` instead of `width` for children elements (e.g. .secondary) in order to consider calculating the padding and margin.